# How to derive gravitational acceleration from lapse function in General Relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, acceleration, hamiltonian-formalism

The lapse function in General Relativity for Schwarzschild space-time is defined as
$$\frac{d\tau}{dt}\equiv\alpha=(-g_{00})^{1/2}=(1-2/r)^{1/2},$$
where $\alpha$ is the lapse function. In [Thorne et al. (1986)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1986bhmp.book.....T/abstract), the authors define a gravitational potential at page 15 based on the lapse function and they write the gravitational acceleration as follows:
$$\vec{g}=-\vec{\nabla} \ln\alpha$$

I could not not find any clue how to prove this formula. Can someone help me with this?

Any help to derive this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may look it up in books on 3+1 formalism of General Relativity, for example, Eric Gourgoulhon's one, see https://relativite.obspm.fr/3p1/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You can find a neat derivation of that equation by Thorne and Macdonald themselves at this [link](https://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/full/gif/1982MNRAS.198..339T/M000001M050.html). Just check Sec.2.2 and 2.3. Your equation is labelled (2.4).

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link to the paper.